Compute $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos{(k\sqrt{1+t^2})}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$
while finding approximation for the following integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}\frac{\cos{\left(k\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}\right)-1}}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}}dx$$
To compute the real part of the integral there, I was able to express this first integral as proportional to
$$\int_{0}^{a\sin(\frac{1}{a})}\frac{1-\cos{(k\sqrt{1+t^2})}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt, k>0,a>0$$
I could easily find a primitive for the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ term but couldn't find any way to simplify the second term..
So any idea how to compute ?
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\cos{(k\sqrt{1+t^2})}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$
(For now on, I tried $u = 1+x^2$ substitution and $u=k\sqrt{1+x^2}$ but maybe I did it wrong)
Thanks,
-Clem

There doesn't seem to be an elementary antiderivative.  Is there a specific range for $x$ on which you want the approximation to be valid?

Mhh would say most important part is for $a>1$ so $x=a\sin(\frac{1}{a})\approx 1 $
